# osx 10.11.1 can't install gevent

Tags: python, gevent

when i install gevent on osx 10.11.1 , it have a question ,i can't fix it .

This is a detailed process I installed

1: sudo port install libevent

2:sudo pip install greenlet

3:sudo pip install gevent

$:sudo pip install gevent

error: could not create '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/greenlet': Operation not permitted

[Here is a detailed description of the picture](http://77fya2.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/111.png)

I do not know where the problem lies, but I have a root privilege of。

please help me,thanks~~

Comment: Did you follow the advice in the error message? _"if executing pip with sudo you may want sudo's -H flag"_

Comment: yean , i  had    sudo pip install pip --upgrade  ; and then ,  sudo -H  pip  install greenlet    , It still   Operation not permitted   [link](http://77fya2.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/33.png)

Answer (score 4):

Try :

```
sudo easy_install gevent==1.1rc1
```

But i would recommend using virtualenv

Answer (score 2):

From the picture of your description, you failed to install **greenlet**. You can fix this by using **easy_install**.

First, install the **greenlet==0.4.10**:

```
sudo easy_install greenlet==0.4.10
```

The result is:

```
Searching for greenlet==0.4.10
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/greenlet/
Best match: greenlet 0.4.10
Downloading     https://pypi.python.org/packages/f2/3f/09412b656067f280cf017ce5b6465e6339089129212425111117be5557d9/greenlet-0.4.10.tar.gz#md5=5351f8ac5196a00d835c2cb1faf75270
Processing greenlet-0.4.10.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-per91O/greenlet-0.4.10/setup.cfg
Running greenlet-0.4.10/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-per91O/greenlet-0.4.10/egg-dist-tmp-5b4Om0
creating /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/greenlet-0.4.10-py2.7-macosx-10.12-intel.egg
Extracting greenlet-0.4.10-py2.7-macosx-10.12-intel.egg to  /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Adding greenlet 0.4.10 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/greenlet-0.4.10-py2.7-macosx-10.12-intel.egg
Processing dependencies for greenlet==0.4.10
Finished processing dependencies for greenlet==0.4.10
```

Then, install the **gevent**:

```
sudo -H pip install gevent
```

I met the same problem when I installed the *Kafka* on my Mac, and I had fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use/try `pip install --user <your_module>`